# Why do some programs have so many I/O Writes on Task Manager even when they're inactive?

Tags: windows

[image]

In the picture above, I/O writes is shown at the extreme-right. My clipboard capturing utility (clipc.exe) somehow has 125,000,000 I/O writes even though it isn't doing anything most of the time. Why is that the case?

Answer (score 2):

Your clipboard utility is probably polling the Windows clipboard constantly, which would involve a lot of I/O.  There are probably better ways to handle clipboard monitoring.  I've tried a few different clipboard tools over the years, but right now I'm using Ditto, which doesn't do any I/O at all when it's idle.

Answer (score 1):

I can't give you an answer to that but I'd suggest downloading [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) which would at least tell you what it's writing which might help you find out what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

USB keyboard and mouse are polled by the operating system which generate activity even if you dont use it. You could lower the polling rate of such USB device to see if this is the cause.

PS\2 style keyboard and mouse arent polled and instead are sending signals to the computer which is fatser and more accurate.